# Can I have more than 16 Desktop "Spaces" on Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, mac, finder, osx-spaces

Is is possible to have more than 16 desktop "[spaces](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1624)" with Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

I know that it does not seem possible at all from the System Preferences settings, but I was wondering if there exists some software tools that would enable one to use more Spaces, say 20-25.

Comment: If you need that many workspaces, it's probably time to get another monitor.

Comment: try a google search for "OS X virtual desktop". I found this:

http://www.codetek.com/ctvd/

Looks like it might support up to 100 virtual desktops (so says the products page: http://www.codetek.com/products.php).

Answer (score 3):

The setting is in `Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` with the keys `workspaces-cols` and `workspaces-rows`, respectively.

Try to set it and then restart Dock. At least on my computer, however, values over four are ignored, so the following procedure should not really help:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-cols 5
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-cols 5
```

and then

```
killall Dock
```

Answer (score 0):

Link up to a monitor, change to non-mirror display, then you can add more desktop in the monitor screen. After you disconnect, you will get more desktops.